# Can GeoServer 2.0.2 access ArcSDE 10.0 databases?

Tags: geoserver, enterprise-geodatabase, plugins

It looks like ArcSDE 10.0 databases are not yet supported...  At least documentation on the geoserver-2.0.2-arcsde-plugin doesn't appear to address it specifically, and I can't get it to work.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the 2.0.2 docs predate 10.0. Please be clearer about what you have tried and why it is not working. This email on the users list (http://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03004.html) suggests it is supported.

Comment: Thanks, iant.  Perhaps I should give the 2.1 branch a go.